# Time differance "in mins" using current date and time stamp

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, duration

How do I work out the duration from the current date and time to cell A1

```
           A                                   B                                 Results
  +-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
1 |20-01-07 07:27:27|=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))-C2      |    5:31:57   |
  +-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
2 |20-01-07 07:27:27|=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))-C2*1440 |  -56307326.9 |
  +-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I have tried this method above but it seems to not use the DATE.

Is there a way I can get it to include the date and also get it to display in minutes

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15EqEkdzcPntTV1K0EfOW_BPcq7zFDNqOMNwEFdQuDIE/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A, TEXT(NOW()-A2:A, "[m]")*1, ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

`=now() - A1` will give you the number of days between the date in A1 and now.

The decimal part of the number if a fraction of a day.

So if you need minutes, try the formula :

```
=(now()-A1)*(24*60)
```

The output will most likely have decimal places which is the number of seconds as fractional minutes.